# Safari: zooming in/out causes some elements to scale differently than others

Tags: safari

This is a problem with desktop Safari (I'm on Safari 7.0.5 on OS X 10.9.4).  I set up a JSBin here to demonstrate the problem (http://jsbin.com/bowuk/1).  There are three divs on this page, and I set the width and height on each of them to be

10 x 10 px

20 x 10 px

20 x 20 px

When I zoom in on the page, I would expect these elements to remain the same size relative to one another, but that's not the case.  When I zoom in the page all of the way, the computed size of the elements (using the Safari inspector) change to:

9.71 x 9.71 px

9.71 x 19.76 px

19.76 x 19.76 px

It's strange that the computed size of the elements change, as well as the different scale factors.  I only see this on Safari.  Just wondering if anybody knows what is happening, and if there is any way to fix this.  I'm working on a project where it is important that elements keep the same size relative to one another no matter what the zoom level.

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: The version is 7.0.5, on OS X 10.9.4